# Unsubscribing uisng shutdown()

Tags: ros, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a vector of subscribers and each subscriber has same callback function. When  i try to clear the vector , code hangs indefinitely. So is there a way to unsubscribe or a way to deallocate the alloted memory.. beside the method mentioned above. I have also tried uisng ros::Subscriber::shutdown to unsubscribe an element of vector and still my code hangs...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57148/unsubscribing-uisng-shutdown()/) by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1610 on 2013-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My intuition says that this should work in principle. Can you come up with a minimal example to test? I am using unsubscribe in my code and it doesn't hang there. If it does, it's consider it a bug.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0